# Comparing two strings - code optimization

Tags: performance-tuning, string-manipulation

I want to compare two strings by counting how many common characters they have at the same position - but overall in all possible alignments of the two strings.

```
SeedRandom[1]
str1 = RandomInteger[{1, 26}, 90] /. 
   Thread[Range[26] -> CharacterRange["A", "Z"]] // StringJoin
str2 = RandomInteger[{1, 26}, 850] /. 
   Thread[Range[26] -> CharacterRange["A", "Z"]] // StringJoin
fu[x_, y_] := 
 Module[{par = Partition[Characters[y], StringLength[x], 1, {1, 1}]},
  Count[Flatten[(Transpose[{#, Characters[x]}] & /@ par), 1], {z_, z_}]
  ]

fu[str1, str2] // Timing
(*{0.046875, 3013}*)
```

This means that strings `str1` and `str2` have `3013` common characters in total in all possible alignments.

Can it be done more efficiently, perhaps without converting strings into lists?

Comment: Is this the same as doing `{c1, c2} = Characters /@ {str1, str2};
Sum[Boole[c1[[i]] == c2[[j]]], {i, Length[c1]}, {j, Length[c2]}]` which also gives 3013? Or more compactly you could do `Total[Outer[Boole@*Equal, c1, c2], 2]`

Comment: ^ note with the above, if you use ToCharacterCode instead of Characters, you get slightly better performance.

Comment: I got an order of a magnitude's speed-up using `fu[x_, y_] := Module[{
   par = Partition[Characters[y], StringLength[x], 1, {1, 1}],
   len = StringLength[x]
   },
  Total[len - HammingDistance[x, StringJoin[#]] & /@ par]
  ]`

Comment: @flinty: Your code is more elegant but no speed gain. C. E.@: Nice speed gain.

Comment: You could try to use ListCorrelate: ListCorrelate[str1, str2, {1, -1}, {}, (Equal[##]) &,(Count[{##}, True]) &]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is

```
fu3 = Dot @@ Lookup[#, Union @@ Keys[#], 0] &[Counts@*ToCharacterCode /@ {#, #2}] &;

Last@Table[fu[str1, str2], {100}] // RepeatedTiming
Last@Table[fu3[str1, str2], {100}] // RepeatedTiming
(* {2.3, 3013} *)
(* {0.0029, 3013} *)
```

Comment: Or  bit faster `fu4 = Dot @@ Lookup[#, Union @@ Keys[#], 0] &[
    Counts /@ ToCharacterCode[{#, #2}]] &;`.